# Problemas con Access-Control-Allow-Origin PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, cors

Buenas estoy tratando de hacer una peticion con ajax desde la pagina

> www.ejemplo.net

hacia la pagina

> www.ejemplo.net/reportecompras

, para ello en la cabecera de

> www.ejemplo.net/reportecompras

estoy poniendo lo siguiente:

```html
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.ejemplo.net/*");
```

Y por lo visto todo va bien siempre y cuando alguien entre a su navegador con la direccion url:

> https://www.ejemplo.net/

pero que pasa si alguien ingresa a su navegador escribiendo la siguiente direccion url:

> https://ejemplo.net/

o

> ejemplo.net/

pues pasa lo siguiente me tira este error el navegador:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.ejemplo.net/reportecompras/?buscar=a' from origin 'https://ejemplo.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.ejemplo.net/*' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>
> GET https://www.ejemplo.net/reportecompras/?buscar=a net::ERR_FAILED

como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: En el lado del cliente (en la *request*), ¿estás definiendo el *header* [`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno nadie respondio la pregunta, pero halle la solucion en san google,dejo aqui la solucion por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.
El truco esta en  no usar url absolutas por ejemplo si quiero hacer una peticion
a "htts://www.ejemplo.net/reportecompras/?buscar=a" en mi codigo deberia poner

```html
xhr.open("GET","/reportecompras.php/?buscar=a");
```

y no

```html
xhr.open("GET","https://www.ejemplo.net/reportecompras.php/?buscar=a");
```